# Getting alt text from image in loop

Tags: jquery, string, instagram, attr

I've got a bit of code that searches Instagram and returns a number of results.  These are displayed in a small grid in the div 'imgDiv'.  The image title is added as 'alt' text for each image and if I put in an `alert('' + title + ');` immediately after the 'prepend' function, I can see that the titles are accurately parsed in full.

The next part of the code lets the user click on an image and see it enlarged.  This part works fine and the correct image is enlarged and the grid is hidden.  I want to add the 'alt text' as a label beneath the enlarged image - and this is where it goes wrong.  Even though I am using a parallel function to the one used to retrieve the img src, when I run the code below, the enlarged image is displayed, the additional div is created, but only the first word of the alt text shows up - the string breaks at the first white space.

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong here:

```
$('#imgDiv').prepend('<img alt=' + title + ' width=89 src= ' + imgurl  + ' onclick =  enlarge(this)>&nbsp;');
            }
       });
    }
function enlarge(el) {
  var source = $(el).attr('src'); 
  var label = $(el).attr('alt');
     $('#imgDiv').css('display', 'none');      
     $('#bigDiv').css('display', 'block').html('<img width = 600 src= ' + source  + '><br><div class=imgTitle>' + label + '</div>')
   }
```

Thanks for any advice/assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!  The error was not in the jquery, but in the fact that the alt text was a string literal.  Light bulb went on and this fixed it:

```
$('#imgDiv').prepend('<img alt="' + title + '" width=89 src= ' + imgurl  + ' onclick =  enlarge(this)>&nbsp;');
```

A simple matter of adding a bit of punctuation.

Thanks to all who answered or thought about it.  I hope this answer helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `find` to target that particular element

Use

```
var label = $(el).find('img').attr('alt');
```

`this` corresponds to the element `$('#imgDiv')` . So you need to find the img which is the descendant of the element.

Comment: That just returns 'undefined'.  The problem seems not to be finding the right string, but getting all of it.  The title text is displayed until the first white space -so, if someone has added a title to their instagram which is an unbroken string of hashtags, the entire string is correctly displayed.  Thanks for your help!